# Surprising (to me) type of a simple F# function

Tags: types, f#

I am writing an F# function as follows to calculate the product of a list of numbers, with an accumulator "r".

```
> let rec proda xs r =
-     match xs with
-     | [] -> r
-     | x::xr -> proda xr (x*r)
- ;;
```

To my surprise, its type of `proda`, according to the F# console is:

```
val proda : xs:int list -> r:int -> int
```

Why isn't the type of `proda`

```
val proda : xs:a' list -> r:a' -> a'
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the argument is inferred to be `int`, because you are using the `*` operator to aggregate the elements of the list in `x * r`. This determines the type of `x` and `r` as `int` and, consequently, the `xs` will become `int list`.

If you wanted to avoid this, you could replace `*` with a function given as an extra argument:

```
let rec proda f xs r =
  match xs with
  | [] -> r
  | x::xr -> proda f xr (f x r)
```

This has the following type:

```
val proda : f:('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> xs:'a list -> r:'b -> 'b
```

This is a very useful function and it happens to be included in the core F# library as `List.fold` (with the last two arguments switched)! It is somewhat more general because the result can be of a different type than the elements of the list (`a` vs. `b`), but it's a simple generalization of what you have.

**EDIT** You are right that `*` can also be used with `float`. To support this, you would have to make the function `inline`. This is a bit tricky, because you cannot do this with a recursive function, so you need to add a nested recursive function:

```ml
let inline proda xs r =
  let rec loop xs r = 
    match xs with
    | [] -> r
    | x::xr -> loop xr (x*r) 
  loop xs r
```

With inline functions, the compiler can infer "static member constraints" which is essentially a way of saying "any type that supports `*`". The syntax is a bit long-winded:

```
val inline proda :
  xs: ^a list -> r: ^b ->  ^b
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( * ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^b)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yet "*" is not limited to ints. It also for floats too! For example, "fun x-> x*2.8" is a function of type float-> float.

Comment: Just found that " fun x y -> x*y" is of type  "int -> int -> int". Surprised.

Comment: You're right - you can make `*` work with both floats and ints using `inline`. See edit.